# Super fast magento 2 store

Tags: magento2.3, pagespeed

I am trying to speed up my Magento 2.3 CE store with no much success. I have installed Varnish and followed all instructions that I could find on web.

I have fast dedicated server, 2 core 8G ubuntu 18.04 apache 2.4 PHP7.2 Varnish 5.2 all dependencies and I can only get 3.6s load time on product page.  I am chasing ghosts or there is fast M2 store out there?

Please give me example store so I can have something to look up to.

Can someone please advise how fast magento can be? is 2s page load achievable?

Could someone please share a link to fast magento store that achieve good result on PageSpeed Insights

Comment: what is your `time to first byte` , do you see magento debug headers `HIT` and `max-age` **>** 0?

Answer (score 0):

Follow these steps must help you speedup your magento

- Disable useless extensions

  php bin/magento module:disable VendorName_PluginName

to re-enable it

```
php bin/magento module:enable VendorName_PluginName
```

- Choose the fastest hosting that you can afford
- Turn on cache
- Turn on Production mode

  php bin/magento deploy:mode:show
- Never Use JS Bundling in:

> You can double check JS bundling is off by going to backend menu
>   Stores > Configuration > Advanced > Developer:

- Enable CSS/JS Minification
- Use Built-in Cache or Varnish
- Use 3rd party Full Page Cache extension, it will make your magento to 2s

Comment: Wouldn't recommend 3rd party extensions for Full page cache, varnish should do the trick if properly set. Also, why do you think js bundling is bad?

Comment: You probably right about 3rd party extension, but they give more options on admin to manage Full page cache, like clear single page cache not whole website cache etc

Comment: And for js bundling, I just followed the reference article on my website, and it worked, my website is pretty much fast now

Comment: Check the detail in: https://servebolt.com/speed-up-magento-2-in-7-easy-steps/

Comment: @Bare js bundling, creates big merged js files (in my case over 2M) that destroy mobile performance

Answer (score -1):

try using on your dedicated server the following technologies:

Nginx, MariaDB, Http2, Php72, Memcache.

I've achieve <2s using the following without any further tweaks.
Also make sure that your JavaScript in code are always set to load last and that images on your homepage are proper sizes, compressed.

Comment: it is unlikely to help with anything ...